# KendoUI Grid remove pre-sorted setting on data list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i've a kendoui grid in a partial view, filled by a server side model object. That's all okay. But the model, IQueryable ist defined to sort by title. In the grid, there are no sorting, or by Id.

I've no possibilities to check the sql executed by the app (SQL Server Express). Is there any setting i need to set or something else, that the presorted list will not be modified?

Here is the view code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DataModel.Buch>(Model)
    .Name("books")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(b => b.Privat).Title("P/G").Width(40).Template(@<text>
    @if (item.Privat)
    {
        <img src="~/Images/home_32.png" alt="private" title="privates Buch" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Images/company_32.png" alt="business" title="TLRZ-eigenes Buch" />
    }
    </text>);
        columns.Bound(b => b.Titel).Template(@<text>@Html.ActionLink(item.Titel, "Details", "Book", new { id = item.Id }, null)</text>);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DatumAufnahme).Title("Aufnahme").Format("{0:d}").Width(120);
        columns.Bound(b => b.Isbn).Title("ISBN");
        columns.Bound(b => b.Verlag);
        columns.Bound(b => b.Author).Title("Autor");
        columns.Bound(b => b.Ausgeliehen).Template(@<text>
    @if (item.Ausgeliehen)
    {
        <span data-sid="@item.Leihen.Single(l => !l.Rueckgabedatum.HasValue).BenutzerSid" data-field="FullName"><img src='/Images/loader_circle_16.gif' alt='lade' />(ja...)</span>
    }
    else
    {
        <span>nein</span>
    }
    </text>);
        columns.Bound(p => p.BenutzerSid).Title("Verantwortliche(r)").Template(@<span data-sid="@item.BenutzerSid" data-field="FullName"><i><img src='/Images/loader_circle_16.gif' alt='lade' />(wird geladen...)</i></span>);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable())
```

Thanks.

Comment: I use the ASP.NET MVC wrapper and server-side bindung. Look at the code: Kendo().Grid<...>(Model)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial sorting direction should be configured as shown in [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#sort) part of the documentation.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Server()
    .Sort(sort =>
    {
        // Sort by UnitsInStock in descending order
        sort.Add(p => p.UnitsInStock).Descending();
        // then by ProductName in ascending order
        sort.Add(p => p.ProductName);
    })
)
```